# reading nested tag xml file in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

i have the following xml file

```
<rec><name><fname>Ravi</fname><lname>kumar</lname></name>
<age>25</age><contact>
<email><personal>ravi@gmail.com</personal>
<official>ravi@infy.com</official></email>
<phone><mobile>12345</mobile>
<office>12346</office>
<residence>12347</residence></phone></contact></rec>
```

How to read the nested tags!! i am new to hive

Comment: you can use xpath_string/xpath_int to parse

Comment: thanks @ankur by using xpath_string() i can read the 1st level data but how to read nested data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select xpath_string(line,'rec/name/fname'),xpath_string(line,'rec/name/lname'),xpath_int(line,'rec/age'),
...........................................
xpath_string(line,'rec/contact/phone/residence') from <table_name>;
```

Hope this will help..